# Engine over filled with oil

Tags: oil, turbocharger, head-gasket, vauxhall

This is a 2007 Vauxhall Antara 2.0 L CDTI.

Four months ago I took my car to a local garage chain to do some tyre adjustments and thought I might as well let them change my oil and oil filter. All this was done and I didn't check the works. Two days ago the car broke down.  There was loads of white smoke behind me when this happened. I was doing a 10 mile trip and as I went in 3rd gear to about 4.5k rpm something 'blew'. I noticed some coolant splashed near the expansion bottle and a few drips underneath the engine. At the back of the exhaust it was wet and oily.

Had to get it recovered because it wouldn't start anymore and has no compression. Had a quick check and can confirm that there is no coolant in the oil and no oil in the coolant, as I suspected a blown head gasket first. Only thing I can also confirm is there is a lot of oil in the car. See the picture below.

Is it possible that they filled my car and forgot to drain it before? It seems it's double the amount that it was supposed to be .. :(

In big need of the car, got a baby on the way in a few weeks time. Thanks for taking your time to read all of this!

[image: Oil overfill]

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! If there was extra oil, it wasn't doing the engine any good, that's for sure. From the sounds of it, I'd suggest you are having a problem with your turbocharger. An easy way to check it is to pull the cold side intake piping off of the turbo, then play with the impeller to see if there is any play in it and looking also for free spin movement. If there's *any* play, or it doesn't seem like it's turning freely, there's an issue there.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I was thinking the turbo may have suffered damage, but would the car not still turn on? Last time it was on(when it broke) I had it running once more before it didn't want to turn on anymore, it was running very rough and loads of white smoke, if you were to accelerate a bit  ( out of gear ) it would then accelerate itself to max rpm and blow alot of smoke

Comment: You mention CDTI - have you checked the oil to make sure it is not contaminated with diesel? Some diesels can over-fuel and the excess collects in the sump causing damage... A possible indication is if the fuel consumption got worse over the last month or so? But this is difficult to tell if you only put in small amounts - easier if you fill the tank full...

Comment: How can I check if the diesel is/not contaminated with diesel? I think the MPG is poor roughly 24 MPG, I usually only put small amounts in and I drive 3 times per week a 15 mile trip... car has 64k miles on it. It is very possible it could be diesel in the oil, and that's how its so much of the oil in it. Do you reckon the flood began after the white smoke started and thats when the oil level rise? Something caused it to blow ...Thanks Solar Mike and Paulster2

Comment: It is whether the engine oil is contaminated with diesel...

Comment: Damn yeah , Mistake on my end. I meant how to check if the OIL is contaminated with Diesel. I will google and see what techniques out there. Thanks for the tip

Comment: Solar Mike not sure if you are familiar with the paper towel test for diesel contamination into oil, I have done it , and got a pic. https://imgur.com/a/cU9VM

Comment: Smell is a good start...

Answer (score -1):

You need to clear, intercooler, intake, outlets, inlets and turbo. There’s oil in the System. Maxing out is known as a diesel runaway. And it’s because you have oil running into your combustion chamber.